# Integer -> double unboxes, but Double -> int doesn't unbox. Why?

Tags: java, data-conversion, primitive, boxing

To avoid confusion, I'm looking for the rule/JLS entry.

- I'm not asking why `Double -> int` would fail, I'm asking about the *way* it fails
- I'm aware of the lossy conversion, as I've mentioned in my question - I'm not asking about data loss between `double -> int`
- I'm not asking for someone's "best guess" on why the developers designed it this way

I'm asking why `Integer -> double` performs a conversion (unbox & widening), while `Double -> int` performs no conversion (not even unboxing)

I'm looking for the JLS entry that mentions this `Reference -> primitive` conversion inconsistency, where unboxing occurs in one situation, but not the other.

---

This `Integer -> double` conversion compiles with no error

```
double d = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

It implies the following occurs:

1. `Integer` is [unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) to `int`
2. the `int` value undergoes a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) from `int -> double`

`Integer` is unboxed. The unboxed value is then widened. This gives the same behavior as `int -> double`

---

The creates the assumpsion that `Double -> int` will also unbox, giving the same behavior as `double -> int`

For the code

```
int i = Double.valueOf(1);
```

I would expect the error message

> lossy conversion from double to int

Assuming the `Double` gets unboxed, we should observe the same behavior as `double -> int`

Instead, we get a typing error

> Cannot convert Double to int

---

What is the explanation behind this behavior?

Why does unboxing occur between `Integer -> double`, but no unboxing occurs between `Double -> int`?

Why are these congruent:

- `Integer -> double`
- `int -> double`

But these aren't:

- `Double -> int`
- `double -> int`

Comment: Because it is easier to "upgrade" an integer to a float. If you go the other way, you sacrifice precision. As you described, this is a lossy conversion.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl So why wouldn't we get a lossy conversion message, as expected? Why is it a type error? Why does unboxing occur with `Integer -> double`, but doesn't seem to occur with `Double -> int`? That's the question I'm asking

Comment: Why should it try unboxing, if it knows it'll still get a type error at the other end?

Comment: double-to-int and Double-to-int are lossy conversions. Originally there was just a double-to-int giving C++ like warning. But nowadays a simple `(int)` cast is the expected style. Hence for Double-to-int no effort was made to just allow this unclear and indirect two-step conversion. _Of course I was not present at the language design, but one would need to do implicitly `(int)(double)`._

Comment: "Why did they design it this way"-questions are opinion based, and off-topic

Comment: @Jorn I'm not asking why they designed it this way. I've updated my question.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm not asking about widening/narrowing. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. To me it boils down to why the error message was put the way it was. I tend to agree that it’s imprecise, but it’s not wrong. Asking why `Double` isn’t unboxed in a code line that cannot be compiled at all doesn’t make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a table showing allowed conversions within [§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5):

> - signifies no conversion allowed
> - ω signifies widening primitive conversion
> - ⊗ signifies unboxing conversion

[image]

The table shows `Integer -> double` performs unboxing & widening conversions, but `Double -> int` does not perform unboxing.

Since unboxing doesn't occur, we get a type error rather than a lossy conversion error.

Comment: That table shows allowed conversions in a "casting context". For instance, this table shows you that `(int) Double.valueOf(1)` does not compile. But your code doesn't use a cast operator, but a plain assignment, i.e. `int i = Double.valueOf(1)`, for which different rules apply.

Comment: @meriton it doesn't need a cast operator, cause implicit casting exists

Answer (score 2):

`Double` only has two `valueOf` methods: [one for `String` input](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) and [one for `double` inputs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-double-).

So, while you wrote `Double.valueOf(1)` where that `1` is clearly an `int`, the method signature is `valueOf(double)` so (if this were to even run) your `int` value would get upgraded to a `double` and *then* the method runs. As such, your `int i = Double.valueOf(1)` is really `int i = Double.valueOf(1.0)` to which the Java compiler goes "a double can't be safely converted to an int, so: no".

Although of course, it doesn't even need to do that: it knows the return value for `Double.valueOf` is a `Double`, no matter what you've put in, so it sees code that tries to assign a Double to an int, knows this is impossible, and without caring about anything else, it'll go "RHS is incompatible with LHS, so: no".

Though interestingly, "*The[sic] creates the assumpsion[sic] that `Double -> int` will also unbox*" is both wrong (no value unboxing happens) and not entirely wrong (there's type "unboxing"). You're giving Java an assignment with types `int = Double`, Java sees incompatible types, but also knows that this is a primitive assignment and that `Double` can unbox to the primitive `double`. However, as that's still an incompatible assignment, Java nopes out with the original int/Double incompatibility error (so that you know "what's wrong with your code" rather than "what's wrong in whatever code magic the parser applied")

Comment: Some valid points, _+1_.

Comment: I wasn't assuming `Double.valueOf(1)` accepted an `int`. I could have written `Double.valueOf(...)`. You keep talking as if you were the compiler or were looking through the eyes of the compiler , such as "Java sees incompatible types" and "RHS is incompatible with LHS, so: no", but I'm not looking for someone's perspective on it, rather a snippit from the devs themselves that explain the behavior. Do you have a reference from the JLS that explains the behavior?

Comment: The docs. E.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html and all the other ones explaining in more detail than anyone would ever want exactly how the compiler and JVM work. Java is _extremely_ exhaustively documented.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know, I was asking for the section that covered this rule

Comment: and lo and behold, _reading the documentation made you find it_. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... This gives the same behavior as `int -> double` ..."*

That's what the conversion is.  The *Integer* object is *un-boxed* to an *int*.
There is never an *Integer* to *double*.

> *"... Assuming the `Double` gets unboxed, we should observe the same behavior as `double -> int` ..."*

I don't expect that from *Java* at all.
And, unfortunately, I don't have the metrics.

I imagine if the value can't *un-box* and assign in a single operation, the compiler would fail.

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid confusion, I'm looking for the rule/JLS entry.
>
> - I'm not asking why Double -> int would fail, I'm asking about the *way* it fails

You're asking for something which doesn't exist.

The Java Language Specification does not generally mandate the wording of compilation errors. In particular, the [relevant section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) of the Java Language Specification merely describes which implicit conversions are permitted in an assignment context, but does not enumerate the combinations of conversions that aren't permitted, let alone which error message should be given in each case (or how to choose the message if several cases apply).

All the specification mandates is that the compiler rejects invalid conversions, how it words the message is up to the compiler implementors, and different compilers actually emit different messages.

For instance, if you ask the Eclipse Compiler for Java to compile

```
int i = Math.PI;
int j = Double.valueOf(Math.PI);
```

it says:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Double to int
```

Comment: "It doesnt exist", that's not true. It's under conversion context, someone on Discord helped me find it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5

Comment: As your link puts it: "Casting contexts allow the operand of a cast expression (§15.16) to be converted to the type explicitly named by the cast operator. Compared to assignment contexts and invocation contexts, casting contexts allow the use of more of the conversions defined in §5.1, and allow more combinations of those conversions."

Comment: That is, that table describes how code using an explicit type cast is type checked. Your code doesn't use a cast operator, and therefore that table does not apply.

Comment: I understand the confusion with "casting _expression_", but if that were the case, `Object obj = 5;` would require an explicit cast if the table only included explicit casts. It also includes implicit casts. It defines the rule for the conversion, explicit or implicit